# Scores of tod_detecting / tod_training in "Solutions in Perceptions Challenge 2011" , details available?

Tags: ros, opencv, object-recognition, tod-detecting, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, are there details on how well ROS packages `tod_training` and `tod_detecting` performed at *"Solutions in Perceptions Challenge 2011"* at ICRA in Shanghai 2011? These two ROS packages have been used for comparison to solutions submitted by participating contesters. According to the score function, winner's team got ca. 69% of max. score and `tod_training+tod_detecting` combo got 50.86%. The results are nice, but I am wondering about the `tod_training+tod_detecting` combo:

- choice of algorithms
- choice of hyperparameters
- used svn revision
- handling of limited computation times

For those accustomed to tod_*, it burns down to the question, whether one of the svn revisions has been used in the contest without further modification, and what the `features.config.yaml` and `config.yaml` (describing the parameter set) have looked like.

[image: image description]

btw, this is the report which I am missing as well as
the parameter configuration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10017/scores-of-tod_detecting-/-tod_training-in-%22solutions-in-perceptions-challenge-2011%22-,-details-available?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-05-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-05-29**:
I also attempted to ask guys from the challenge directly. Maybe some of the information has been presented only verbally at ICRA itself. There's no presentations or details on the Challenge website (neither on YouTube). Anyone in the community had the opportunity to watch the Challenge in Shanghai?

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-05-29**:
I have also been foraying for further information on the OpenCV mailing list, see http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/80424 .  Anybody investigating into this matter as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The version of TOD used for the contest is a private version that was forced into the contest stub code.  This is not a public repository.

tod_* is in a state of flux, and will soon be removed in its current form.  Please do not depend on it, or expect it to work.

---

Originally posted by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) with karma: 225 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2